# No output when I run this code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This bit of code I'm doing was for practice with "While loops". When I run this code to count the amount of digits in a number, java doesn't output anything, which I found odd because usually when I get something wrong it'd give me an error, but this one ran without error. Is someone able to point out and explain why no output is showing?

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class DigitCounter
{
   public static int countDigits( int number )
 {
  int sum=0;
  while(number>0);
  {
    sum++;
    number = number/10;
  }
  return sum; 
 }
}

\\new class
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class DigitCounterRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
   out.println(DigitCounter.countDigits(234));
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can execute a `main` in an `inner` class (there is no enclosing instance). Move `main` to the outer `DigitCounter` class.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The `import static` is at the top. It looks like an inner class to me.

Comment: Oops sorry overlooked that

Comment: Why not put some debug output statements into your DigitCounter.countDigits() method and see what's going on in there? What have you tried doing to debug this yourself?

Comment: The two classes are not together if that's what you mean, forgot to add in the import static for the runner class

Comment: @Trevor when I put output statements in the count digits method there is still no output.

Comment: @Warren: Given the answer below, this is *exactly* why your first step should always be to use a debugger.  Stepping through the code would have shown exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delete `;` after `while(number>0);` in your `countDigits( int number )` method because it's block there.
You should have the body of `countDigits( int number )` method like that:

```
public static int countDigits( int number )
     {
      int sum=0;
      while(number>0)
      {
        sum++;
        number = number/10;
      }
      return sum; 
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked up "semicolon after while loops" after I saw this answer and I understand why what I put doesn't work.